# How to use one UIPickerView's to show more than one Picker in same UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm a complete beginner on iOS dev and I want to create a little iOS application.On this page, I need to use one UIPickerView to create more than one picker in the UIView. However,  I don't know the amounts of picks before the run time.

Now:
[This is the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZSv1.png)

I would like to do like this one:
[The amount of picker is unknown before run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8A5q.png)

Code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var Pickers: UIPickerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
   for index in 1...neverCount{
   array.append(String(index))
       }
   }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,titleForRow row:Int,forComponent component:Int ) -> String!{

    return array[row]
}
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    print(self.array[pickerView .selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])

    self.choice = Int(self.array[pickerView .selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])!
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,numberOfRowsInComponent component:Int ) -> Int{
    return array.count
}
 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

English is not my mother tongue, please excuse any errors on my part.

Comment: Array is a type. append is an instance method, not static. Are you sure that `Array.append(String(index))` compiles ? it if does, where is Array declared. It is Swift convention to name all your vars starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: I have declared var Array = [String](), Sorry for my bad Programming style.

Comment: you can't.  change it to lowercase  `var array: [String] = [ ]`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.